# How do I set a variable from inside a function?

Tags: php

How do I set a variable from inside a function?
`$test` is supposed to be an object, I don't know if that makes a difference.

```
<?php
    $test;

    function hi() {
        $test = new obj();
    }
?>
```

Whenever I check if `$test` is set, I get false. This is not a class so I can't do `$this->test`

Comment: sorry I couldn't find an answer. thanks for the help though

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

function hi() {
    $test = new obj();
    return $test;
}

$test=hi();
?>
```